# Left Sidebar icons of Jenkins are black and white rather than coloured as all online Jenkins articles I've seen. What can I change?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I just installed a local Jenkins in Windows, Jenkins 2.424, and the icons on my left sidebar are black and white:

[image]

whereas all icons I've seen for Jenkins in online articles are coloured. Do you know what I can change to have it look like the following?

[image]

Comment: Had a look at an old version from 2021, v Jenkins 2.303.3, and I've got the coloured icons I was trying to have on the newer one.

I guess the guys close to the tool knew about this change, but then the question is, can I somehow bring them back to my instance? I cannot find any way to change from the current defaults to the old set of icons...

Comment: The monochromatic icons were slowly introduced as part of a UI overhaul with 2.277.1 in Mar 2021. Many people are [disappointed](https://community.jenkins.io/t/im-disappointed/6036) w/that. What you see around the web are simply old screenshots. The old icons are all png and the new are svg.

Comment: Thank you @IanW, I didn't know about the change after researching the problem and finding out what you mentioned. I didn't see anyone that liked the downgrade to monochromatic icons. I was used to the coloured ones when I was in touched with Jenkins a few years ago and was not feeling comfortable with the new ones the other day when I had to get in touch again. I managed to replaced the ones I use the most, but one needs to do it one by one, converting images oneself, etc... not the most straightforward proccess. They could have left the option for the user to decide or something. Thank you

Comment: Also [this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/14909/13379). Now that the icon replacements have been more fully implemented (you'll note there's now color in your status icons), it may be easier to override/replace the SVG.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to finally do it. Not the most straight forward process as one needs to replace things manually but it's doable if anyone likes more the coloured icons.

[image]

[image]